# Get the view definition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

After creation of a view, is there any command to get the query that created the view in mysql.

I can save the query somewhere but mysql command can be useful anytime.

Comment: some example would be really useful for us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use show create

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name
```